# Bitnami Redmine in AWS: Cannot Send Test Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, redmine, bitnami

I have been trying to set up email in Bitnami Redmine in Amazon Web Services (AWS), and I am getting the following error whenever I try to send a test email:

> An error occurred while sending mail (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

Below is my configuration:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: "company's address as specified in outlook settings" 
      port: 25
```

I have tried the exact same configuration using the Bitnami Redmine Stack accessed from localhost, and it works fine, but after launching Redmine in AWS, the configuration no longer works. I have tried using "production" instead of "default" and I still get the same error. I have also tried pinging the company address and using the IP address instead and I still get an error. It works in localhost, but not in AWS.

I think the issue could be VPN related, because Localhost only works when I am connected to VPN.

Is there any way around this for AWS?

Thank you.

Comment: How about your DNS? Can you ping your mail server from your Redmine server?

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be related with you using `25` port. Try to use a secure port (`485` or `587` usually) and enabling `tls` options.

In Bitnami documentation you can find an example of how do this [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/redmine/#how-to-configure-outbound-email-settings)

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I tried ports 485 and 587 (with enabling TLS options) and it still did not work with my company address.  I contacted my IT administrator, and found out that our mail server is not reachable from the internet.

I will just use Gmail's SMTP server on port 587 for now, and I may consider something like Amazon SES in the future.  It works fine with Gmail's server.